# How to split a HTML page without access to the HTML, e.g. using split.js?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a static HTML page where I can not make changes to the HTML part, so I believe that I can only modify the page using JavaScript.

I'd like to split the page into two parts by a horizontal split/gutter, possibly by using  [split.js](https://split.js.org/#/).

The page has only two divs like this

```
<body>
<div class=Foo>
<div align=center>
...
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Is it possible to put a split into this page?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give a simple HTML input, and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used split.js but is this what you're after? You can optimise the code but a split can be achieved by removing the elements and styling them and adding them back in. JS code:

```
const outerDiv = document.querySelector('body > div');
const innerDiv = document.querySelector('body > div > div');
const outerFirst = outerDiv.firstElementChild;
outerDiv.removeChild(outerFirst);
innerDiv.removeAttribute('align');
outerDiv.removeAttribute('class');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
body.innerHTML = '';
outerDiv.style.width = '50%';
outerDiv.style.float = 'left';
innerDiv.style.width = '50%';
innerDiv.style.float = 'left';
body.appendChild(outerDiv);
body.appendChild(innerDiv);
```

EDIT: Horizontal split:

```
const outerDiv = document.querySelector('body > div');
const innerDiv = document.querySelector('body > div > div');
const outerFirst = outerDiv.firstElementChild;
outerDiv.removeChild(outerFirst);
innerDiv.removeAttribute('align');
outerDiv.removeAttribute('class');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
body.innerHTML = '';
body.appendChild(outerDiv);
body.appendChild(innerDiv);
Split([outerDiv, innerDiv], {
    direction: 'vertical',
    sizes: [50, 50]
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I can see the principle from your example. However, I believe that your code splits the document vertically and puts the two existing divs side by side. What I want to do is adding a horizontal split line "over" the entire document as is, and show the entire document in both of the new divisions.

Comment: I tried using split js on the initial document but ran into an error which is caused by the child to parent relationship between the divs. I'm not well accustomed to split js so I'm not sure how to go about splitting the original document without altering the document structure first. You could 'flatten' the document structure as I did originally (ignore the styling) and then use split js, which seems to work. Edited my original post.

Comment: Thanks very much, will try and report back